# Sylius: Why does my tax-amount indication disappear on Checkout?

Tags: symfony, checkout, sylius

*My issue is quite simple:* When I view my cart it properly shows that 21% of the total cost is taxes. Updating my cart correctly alters this tax-amount. When I start the checkout process and fill in my address, payment and shipping options I am prompted with a confirmation view (finalize) before I start my payment.

On this finalize step it shows that there are no taxes applied and the total costs is the exact sum of all my products (100%), whereas in the cart it shows 79% of total costs + 21% taxes.

Any clue where this behavior comes from? I can see no faults in my configuration.

**Edit:** It's worth noting that it also shows **€0,00** taxes when viewing My Orders at `/account/orders/{orderId}`

**Edit 2:** I'm using version [0.10.0 #62973cabcf](https://api.github.com/repos/Sylius/SyliusCoreBundle/zipball/62973cabcf78e089b30a41cdaee674efd3e2121a)

Comment: What Sylius version are you using? Did you customize any OrderProcessing components?

Comment: Stupid of me to not include version information, I've updated the main post with this. I did not modify any `OrderProcessing` component as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok, could you write down your tax configuration - all tax categories, tax rates, zones. This is important, cause https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/features/frontend/checkout_taxation.feature is passing and it reproduces your scenario.